# How to lazily fetch groups in JOOQ?

Tags: java, stream, jooq

I'm trying to write a query in which I fetch child records for my aggregate root using `leftJoin` like this:

```java
dslContext.select()
    .from(PARENT)
    .leftJoin(CHILD)
    .on(CHILD.PARENT_ID.eq(PARENT.ID))
    .stream()
```

My problem is that I need to use `stream` because there are a very big number of records but this way I can't use `fetchGroups` which I would normally use when I need parent-child records.

This is how I'd use `fetchGroups`:

```java
dslContext.select()
    .from(PARENT)
    .leftJoin(CHILD)
    .on(CHILD.PARENT_ID.eq(PARENT.ID))
    .fetchGroups(Parent.class, Child.class)
```

which would create a nice `Map<Parent, Child>` for me.

I tried to `collect` using `Collectors.groupingBy` but it is not straightforward how to use it and the docs don't explain it either.

How can I fetch parent-child records in one go lazily?

Comment: I solved it by combining rxjava/2 with jooq. Also remember to set the fetchsize in your jdbc driver

Comment: I'm not using rxjava and I don't want to.

Answer (score 6):

In jOOQ 3.11, we have added a new [`ResultQuery.collect()`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7469) method, and we are planning on re-implementing most of our `fetchXYZ()` logic as standard [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) implementations, which can then be used with `Stream` to achieve exactly what you're looking for. The main driver for this is to avoid the proliferation of more of these `fetchXYZ()` overloads, and to offer more composability.

You can do it manually, of course:

#### Using `Stream`, in case you want to add additional operations to the stream pipeline

```
// Don't forget, this is a resourceful stream!
try (Stream<Record> stream = dslContext.select()
    .from(PARENT)
    .leftJoin(CHILD)
    .on(CHILD.PARENT_ID.eq(PARENT.ID))
    .stream()) {

    Map<Parent, List<Child>> result = stream.collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.into(Parent.class),
            Collectors.mapping(r -> r.into(Child.class), Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
}
```

The Javadoc of [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) has a similar example.

#### Using `ResultQuery.collect()`, if you don't need the stream pipeline.

Alternatively, using jOOQ 3.11's `ResultQuery.collect()`

```
Map<Parent, List<Child>> result = dslContext
    .select()
    .from(PARENT)
    .leftJoin(CHILD)
    .on(CHILD.PARENT_ID.eq(PARENT.ID))
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.into(Parent.class),
            Collectors.mapping(r -> r.into(Child.class), Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
```